# Meterpreter Webcam_snap warnings

Tags: exploit, metasploit, meterpreter

Since I updated metasploit every time I run the webcam_snap command in meterpreter in recieve lots of warnings like the ones below, why do they appear?

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:498:67: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:509:70: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:520:68: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:530:70: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:541:67: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:551:70: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:571:72: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:581:72: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:594:69: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:654:72: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:664:74: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:675:58: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:685:72: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:744:71: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:754:73: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:765:58: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:775:72: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:1280:68: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:1289:70: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:1298:67: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:1307:70: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:1518:72: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:2130:9: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:2130:9: Expected a string.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:2429:72: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:2440:74: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:2449:71: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:2458:74: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:2757:55: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:3719:8: not a number

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:3719:17: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:3956:14: not a number

(eog:2568): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained-dark.css:3956:14: Expected a string.
```

Comment: This is not an issue with metasploit, it is an issue with your local installation of "eye of gnome" or theme. Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear because `Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.` its an issue with the `gtk-contained-dark.css`

Its only a warning, and only a warning about CSS stuff ... you should be fine.